# WordPress Anonymous Postings?

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, content-management-system, customization

My client wants to create a form on his new WP site that when filled out and submitted will be submitted to his admin post queue to approve and if he approves gets posted on his site in the "blog" (which is actually a bunch of guitar like tabs). The form would be custom and have custom fields. Below is the form, but in the old design before I did a refresh on it.

So, how hard would this be? He does **not** want it in the WP admin panel which i began to do, but outside in a page like `/contribute`

[image]

Comment: This question is probably more suited to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Awh, i didnt realize they had that. Is there a way to move it? I don't wanna cross post...

Answer (score 0):

The [Anonymous Posting plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/anon-posting/) appears to do what you're looking for.

Comment: **NOTE:** Plugin pages lists support upto 2.8.6, WP is currently on version 3.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TDO Mini Forms plugin.

If you're looking to create the form using native Wordpress functions, check out wp_insert_post.

Sorry I can't provide the hyperlinks because I'm a new Stack Overflow user. :-/

Answer (score -1):

You can try TDO Mini Forms plugin.The link to the plugin is [here.](http://thedeadone.net/download/tdo-mini-forms-wordpress-plugin/)

Click "Temporary Mirror" link for downloading the plugin in the above site.